# Dissecting HTTP-Capture

Tags: tcpdump

I have the below HTTP-get capture. I am trying to learn to dissect it manually using protocols and packet math. And am struggling with the following questions. This is not a graded project, just something that was recommend I learn.

1. What is the TCP header length
2. What is the starting byte for the TCP header
3. What is the ending byte for the TCP header
4. How many IPv4 conversations occurred

   ```
   0x0000:  4500 0158 0505 4000 4006 18b1 c0a8 4b76
   0x0010:  174e f87d c0c6 0050 5fa4 6e6c 8b48 e7eb
   0x0020:  8018 001c 1d35 0000 0101 080a 5079 6b75
   0x0030:  26d4 b91a 4745 5420 2f6c 6962 7261 7279
   0x0040:  2f38 2e34 2f64 6170 6d73 6e2e 6a73 2048
   0x0050:  5454 502f 312e 310d 0a48 6f73 743a 2061
   0x0060:  6473 312e 6d73 6164 732e 6e65 740d 0a55
   0x0070:  7365 722d 4167 656e 743a 204d 6f7a 696c
   0x0080:  6c61 2f35 2e30 2028 5831 313b 204c 696e
   0x0090:  7578 2078 3836 5f36 343b 2072 763a 3338
   0x00a0:  2e30 2920 4765 636b 6f2f 3230 3130 3031
   0x00b0:  3031 2046 6972 6566 6f78 2f33 382e 3020
   0x00c0:  4963 6577 6561 7365 6c2f 3338 2e32 2e31
   0x00d0:  0d0a 4163 6365 7074 3a20 2a2f 2a0d 0a41
   0x00e0:  6363 6570 742d 4c61 6e67 7561 6765 3a20
   0x00f0:  656e 2d55 532c 656e 3b71 3d30 2e35 0d0a
   0x0100:  4163 6365 7074 2d45 6e63 6f64 696e 673a
   0x0110:  2067 7a69 702c 2064 6566 6c61 7465 0d0a
   0x0120:  5265 6665 7265 723a 2068 7474 703a 2f2f
   0x0130:  7777 772e 6d73 6e2e 636f 6d2f 0d0a 436f
   0x0140:  6e6e 6563 7469 6f6e 3a20 6b65 6570 2d61
   0x0150:  6c69 7665 0d0a 0d0a
   ```

Comment: Have you tried opening your dump in [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org)?  It is a great tool for understanding protocols.  It will break down all of the protocols involved in the data you capture.

Comment: It's not good to use phrases like you have, to say "HTTP-get capture"  as if that's some kind of standard way of saying it.. like a standard term, when it isn't. It's clear what you mean, but still, imagine somebody reads that and then copies the term off you. You could say you're looking at a dump from tcpdump, that includes an HTTP GET Request. And by the way, heavyd's suggestion is spot on advice,  it's exactly what I would've said had he not already said it.  You can use wireshark to make a capture too.

Comment: Huh? It _is_ a capture of a HTTP GET request, is it not? I'd check with English.SE but both ways of saying it seem rather okay to me. And new words and terms get invented quite often; it doesn't seem to be worth panicking over.

Comment: Before decoding any network traffic or whatever, you’d first need to parse the [libpcap file format](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat). You can’t just look at the hex dump and see stuff.

Comment: First I want to thank you for all your help. I am sorry about the HTTP-get capture this is what I was told it was. What I have is just a email with the dump in text as above. I have a friend that is trying to teach me this and sent me the above the questions. Is there a way to make a pcap file with the above text to analyze in wireshark?

Comment: @MarcWeymouth Ask your friend to send you the pcap file ...

Comment: Hm, I’m getting the feeling this will be more suited for chat, but whatever. You can [“reverse hexdump”](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/doing-reverse-hex-dump) the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good exercise for understanding how various protocols are structured.  In order to get the most out of it, you'll need to understand the IP and TCP header formats.

First, read section 3.1 of RFC 791 - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791

Second, read section 3.1 of RFC 793 - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793

Third, use what you learned in the first two steps to try and answer the questions.

Finally, compare what you learned to the output below, which is a breakdown of the various headers.

```
4500:      IP Version(4 = IPv4), Header Length (5 = 20 bytes)  and DSCP/ECN
0158:      IP packet length (158 = 344 bytes)
0505:      IP Identification
4000:      IP Flags and Fragment Offset (40 = Do not fragment)
4006:      TTL (40 = 64) and encapsulated protocol version (6 = TCP)
18b1:      IP header checksum
C0a8 4b76: Src IP
174e f87d: Dst IP
C0c6:      Src Port (49350)
0050:      Dst Port (80)
5fa4 6e6c: Seq Number
8b48 e7eb: Ack Number
8018:      Header length (8 = 32) TCP Flags (18 = PSH-ACK)
001c:      TCP Win Size (28) <--don't know scale factor
1d35:      TCP checksum
0000:      Urgent Pointer
0101 080a 5079 6b75 26d4 b91a:  TCP Options 

      0101:    NOP, NOP
      08:      Option Kind (08 = Timestamp)
      0a:      Length of 10 bytes
      50796b75:Timestamp 
      26d4b91a:Timestamp echo reply

4745:      HTTP GET
0d0a:      Last CRLF indicates the end of the HTTP request
```